# How to keep a global storage area type independent in C?

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

I have to secure space in advance sufficient for up to 4k total entries divided between two different types, in any proportion, then fill it with data.  I thought I'd allocate space sufficient for 4k of the larger type, and then decide upon filling it up with data what kind it actually is.  I'm running into an issue where the compiler tells me **error (etoa:1554): illegal type(s): ptr-to-void '+' int**.

In my init function, I allocate the space something like this:

```
ser_dat_ch = calloc(LABEL_T_CNT,
        (sizeof(mpls_vpws_t) > sizeof(mpls_vpls_t)
        ? sizeof(mpls_vpws_t)
        : sizeof(mpls_vpls_t)));
```

where `ser_dat_ch` is declared at file scope like so:

```
static void *ser_dat_ch = NULL;
```

When I load data into the structure, I wanted to do something like

```
rv = switch_mpls_vpws_data_get(lab, (mpls_vpws_t*)&ser_dat_ch[lab]);
```

, but this is what gets the compiler barking at me.  What's the problem?

Comment: How does "no dynamic allocations allowed" mesh with `calloc()`?

Comment: I use `calloc()` for the whole area at the very beginning (inside my `init()` function) - which is allowed!

Comment: @cerr, but `calloc()` performs dynamic allocation.  That leaves us uncertain what you mean by "no dynamic allocations allowed".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I use `calloc()` for the whole area at the very beginning (inside my `init()` function) - which is allowed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, I think the simplest solution would be to create a buffer with 4K entries of an union type.

```
struct A {/**/};
struct B {/**/};

union AB {
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};

union AB ser_dat_ch[4000];
```

Comment: Great approach, but bear in mind that the memory layout will be different (less compact), so caching might be less efficient. Not usually a problem, just something to be aware of in high-performance applications.

Comment: Its just as compact in the worst case though, when every single entry is of the larger type.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot index a void pointer, because the size of the element type is unknown. So first downcast your pointer to a particular type, and only then do the indexing:

```
rv = switch_mpls_vpws_data_get(lab, &((mpls_vpws_t*)ser_dat_ch)[lab]);
```

The reason the compiler complains about the `+` operator is that `ser_dat_ch[lab]` is equivalent to `*(ser_dat_ch + lab)`.